# Auto-Generate place holder format string for String.Format()

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Is there a way to tell the `String.Format()` function (without writing my own function) how many placeholders there are dynamically?  It we be great to say `15`, and know I'd have `{0}-{14}` generated for me.  I'm generate text files and I often have more than 25 columns.  It would greatly help.

OK,

I will rephrase my question.  I wanted to know if it is at all possible to tell the `String.Format` function at execution time how many place-holders I want in my format string without typing them all out by hand.

I'm guessing by the responses so far, I will just go ahead and write my own method.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably write your own function -- it's not easy to understand exactly what you're trying to do. String.Join may be useful.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ***Enumerable.Range*** and ***LINQ*** to generate your message string.

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(i => "{" + i + "}").ToArray()
```

generates following string:

```
"{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bit to AlbertEin's response, I don't believe `String.Format` can do this for you out-of-the-box.  You'll need to dynamically create the format string prior to using the `String.Format` method, as in:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();

for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  builder.AppendFormat("{0}", "{" + i + "}");
}

String.Format(builder.ToString(), ...);
```

This isn't exactly readable, though.

Comment: Thanks for the start, I had begun a similar routine.  I guess I should get more sleep before asking something so obvious ;)

Comment: @Chris - No prob.  If the code block you're formatting is any longer than what is shown here please comment accordingly.  This isn't an approach I see often and may confuse many.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `string.Format` when there is no formatting (atleast from what I can see in your question)?  You could use simple concatenation using stringbuilder instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this directly:

Just create a custom IFormatProvider, then use this overload of [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx).

For example, if you want to always have 12 decimal points, you can do:

```
CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone(); // Copy your current culture
NumberFormatInfo nfi = culture.NumberFormat;
nfi.NumberDecimalDigits = 12; // Set to 12 decimal points

string newResult = string.Format(culture, "{0}", myDouble); // Will put it in with 12 decimal points
```